# Conditional Statements in Client Side Templating with Dust.js

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api, conditional-statements, dust.js, client-side-templating

Here is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhmPZ/) of the following to play with. Say I have this JSON data:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "eye-color": "Green"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jill",
            "eye-color": "Blue"
        },
        {
            "name": "James",
            "eye-color": "Green"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I wanted to output all of the peoples' names using [**dust.js**](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs), I would set up the template like so:

```
<ul>
    {#people}
    <li>{name}</li>{~n}
    {/people}
</ul>
```

However, what if:

1) I only wanted to output the names of people with "Green" eyes? Is there a way to do that using [**conditionals in dust**](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-if_condcondition__if_helper_Available_in_Dust_10_release)?

2) I only wanted to output the first two names, regardless of eye color

3) I only wanted to output the second person's name, regardless of eye color

**EDIT: Adding a fourth and fifth scenario:**

4) I only want to display the second and third names (ie index **X** to index **Y**)

5) I only want to output the first two names of people with green eyes (say the list of people went on much longer than the 3 shown above, including more green-eyed people that won't be displayed).

**And one more question:**

Say my JSON has a key / value pair like the following:

```
{ "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] }
```

Is there a way to use {@eq} to check if it contains "tag2" for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all three work, but you will need to use Dust [helpers](https://www.npmjs.org/package/dustjs-helpers).

1: You need the `@eq` helper (I'm also changing the key from `eye-color` to `eyeColor` because dashes can confuse Dust.

```
<ul>
    {#people}
        {@eq key=eyeColor value="Green"}
            <li>{name}</li>{~n}
        {/eq}
    {/people}
</ul>
```

2: You need the `@lt` helper, along with `$idx` (`$idx` is the index of the current item in the array, where the first item is 0).

```
<ul>
    {#people}
        {@lt key=$idx value=2}
            <li>{name}</li>{~n}
        {/lt}
    {/people}
</ul>
```

3: You need the `@eq` helper, along with `$idx`

```
<ul>
    {#people}
        {@eq key=$idx value=1}
            <li>{name}</li>{~n}
        {/eq}
    {/people}
</ul>
```

Comment: awesome! thanks so much. 2 quick addons: 1) how would you display names 2-3 only if there were more than 3 names? and 2) what does the {~n} do? The code seems to work fine without it

Comment: 1) You can nest `{@lt key=$idx value=3}` inside `{@gt key=$idx value=0}`
2) `{~n}` adds a new line, which Dust strips out by default. You probably don't need it.

Comment: thanks smfoote! I added two more scenarios and another related question, could you take a look and let me know if those are possible? that'll be all, I promise :)

Comment: 4th scenario is handled the same as the 2nd scenario, but use `@gt` instead of `@lt`. 5th scenario is probably tough to do with pure dust: it involves modifying state to know how many you have shown already. Do it server-side when creating the JSON or create a custom dust helper to do it.